# Boundedness of linear operators in $L^p$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I was wondering if the following conditions are equivalent for a **linear** operator $T$ between $L^p$ spaces:

i) T maps $L^p$ to $L^p$, that is, if $f \in L^p$ then $Tf \in L^p$.

ii) There exists $C>0$ such that $\|Tf\|_{L^p} \leq C \| f \|_{L^p}$ for every $f \in L^p$.

It is clear to me that $ii)$ implies $i)$ but I can't see clearly the other implication. Can $T$ map $L^p$ to $L^p$ "unboundly"? Does it help if $T$ is **bijective**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $T$ is not necessarily bounded because any infinite dimensional Banach space admits a discontinuous linear operator. Even bijectivity doesn't help: choose Hamel basis in $L_p$ of vectors with norm 1, take countable subfamily. Multiply $n$-th vector of subfamily by $n$. The rest left unchanged. Extend this mapping by linearity. It is bijective but not bounded.

Comment: @userNaN Thank you! Is the statement true if $T^{-1}$ is continuous? In this case $T$ would also be continuous by the Open Mapping Theorem and in this case ii) would always hold, is that right?

Comment: Yes$\phantom{}\phantom{}$

Comment: Typically, this is a situation for the closed graph theorem. Sufficient would be continuity with respect to a coarser Hausdorff topology on $L^p$.